# Any components that give a soldering point on reverse of single layer aluminium board

Tags: components, pcb-layers

I'm designing a single-layer aluminium PCB which will include some touch-sensitive pads, as part of a consumer electronics device. The PCB will cover one of the external faces of an aluminium enclosure, similar to the black PCB top plate shown here

[image: pedal with top plate]

I want to find a way to neatly connect these touch-sensitive pads on the exterior to other circuitry on different boards inside the enclosure.

Are there any components, ideas or techniques I should be considering?

One idea is to connect wires to a small row of solder pads on the outer surface, and thread the wires through holes so that they can attach to the internals, perhaps using a small 3D printed canopy to cover the wires and holes. I don't imagine it'll look as clean as I'd like though.

Comment: Do you think those touch pads will actually work with a conductive backing a thin dielectric layer away? Assuming they are capacitive.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I have been wondering about that. Yes, they are capacitive. It'll be an experiment. I did experiment a while ago with touch pads formed from narrow convoluted tracks. It wasn't a success, but I wasn't sure if that was because of the pad geometry or the substrate.

Comment: If your finger capacitance is tiny compared to the ground substrate, it won’t be sensitive enough. But if you are detecting finger injected grid noise , that might work.

Comment: Read that wrong; I thought you were sensing through the PCB with conductive pads on the inside, disregard the pogo pin answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany and anyone else interested, I ran another experiment today in which I was able to trigger a capacitive touch sensor by touching an exposed trace on a grounded aluminium board. I _think_ that means it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route rectangular slots in the board and turn surface mount headers upside down and stick them through the slot so it hangs by the legs. The plastic shoulders on the header pins will support it against the walls of the hole and be non-conductive.

[image]

https://www.samtec.com/connectors/standard-board-to-board/0100-inch-square-post/si-lite

I'm not familiar with aluminum core PCBs though...is the board house able to coat the walls of drilled holes with a dielectric? Because if they can then all you have to do is use through-hole header pins normally. If you need the header on the side without traces, just stick it through the hole on the side without traces and solder it onto the pads on the trace side like normal.

Comment: I'd need to customise the solder mask on the header's solder pads to prevent any solder from flowing close to the aluminium substrate, but yes, this would work nicely.

Comment: @OutstandingBill You can ease things by selecting headers with an extra long leg length (if they exist, I am not sure if they do. Through-hole comes in different leg legs but I am not sure if SMD does).